# Letter into words

Tags: c++

I'll be placing my class to show additional things that I need work with. Would it work if I did typecasting? Or I just have to learn strings?

```
class NumberBox
{
private:

    int number;
    char letter;

public:

    NumberBox *next_ptr;
    void setNumber(int number)
    {
        this->number = number;
    }

    void setLetter(char letter)
    {
        this->letter = letter;
    }


    int getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }

    int getLetter()
    {
        return letter;
    }
};

int main()

    cout << "Please Give the faction for the first Card" << endl;
    cin >> faction[0];
    if(faction [0] == 's' || faction [0] == 'c' || faction [0] == 'h' || faction [0] == 'd')
    {
        if(faction[0] == 's')
        {
            faction[0] = "spade";
            factionHead_ptr->setLetter("spade");
        }
    }
```

How do you do it? Like If The user input `'s'` then it would be Spade.

Comment: Please do your if check like that: `if(faction [0] == 's' || faction [0] == 'c' || faction [0] == 'h' || faction [0] == 'd')`. It is not relevant to your question, but yours is ugly and incorrect.

Comment: Read about [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in the python tutorial

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) for this purpose. You would build a map from `char` to `std::string`, with one value set of `s`, `c`, `h` and `d`.

A small example of how to use it would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

typedef std::map<char, std::string> suitmap;

int main()
{
    suitmap suits;
    suits['s'] = "spades";
    suits['h'] = "hearts";
    char in;
    std::cout << "Suit?" << std::endl;
    if (std::cin >> in) {
        suitmap::const_iterator it = suits.find(in);
        if (it != suits.end())
            std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "no input" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Adapted to your question, assuming `faction` is an array of `char`s:

```
cin >> faction[0];
// see if we have a match for faction[0] in the map
suitmap::const_iterator it = suits.find(faction[0]);
if (it == suits.end()) {
   // no match
   // print an error or something
} else {
   // match! the string is in it->second
   std::string suit = it->second;
   factionHead_ptr->setLetter(suit);
}
```

Now this won't work at all with your `NumberBox` class since the `setLetter` function expects a single char, and you `letter` member is a char too. So you'd need to change these two to take/be `std::string`s.

If the only thing you want is one letter, then your `letter` member is fine, but you can't put a whole string in a single letter, so your `setLetter` call in `main` doesn't make much sense. So if you do need just a letter, and not a mapping from a single letter to a full suit name, just use a switch statement:

```
cin >> faction[0];
switch (faction[0]) {
  case 's': case 'c': case 'h': case 'd':
    factionHead_ptr->setLetter(faction[0]);
    break;
  default:
    // invalid input given, do something about it
    break;
}
```

Comment: @JuanDelCarlos: it is not _that_ complicated if you look at it line by line, and using standard containers like `map` and `vector` is really important. (And using `std::string`s too.) Added the simple switch variant if you're not after full suit names but just the letter.

Answer (score 1):

this line doesn't work:

```
if(faction [0] == 's' && 'c' && 'h' && 'd')
```

since very part of the if statement is evaluated by itself. E.g: 'c' will always evaluate to true, so the statement has no effect. It should be something like this:

```
if(faction [0] == 's' || faction [0] == 'c' || faction [0] == 'h' || faction [0] == 'd')
```

You could perfectly use a `switch` statement here:

```
switch(faction[0]) {
case 's':
    factionHead_ptr->setLetter("spade");
    break;
case 'c':
    ...
    break;
...

default:
    // code here if none of s, c, h, d
    break;
}
```

**EDIT**: also be careful about your data types. E.g I'm not sure if `faction[0] = "spade";` will work out as expected since `faction[0]` seems to be of type `char` and not a string.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. But, How can I transform a letter into words?

Comment: How do I make a string? I never heard of it.

Comment: @JuanDelCarlos: That depends where you want to put it. I'd suggest that you initialize a new string variable where you put the word.

Comment: @JuanDelCarlos: In C string is a sequence of characters. Use C++ strings: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ 
You have to `#include <string>` first.

Comment: Gives me an error. Error: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char".

Answer (score 1):

You can't chain conditions the way you do. The condition is, if first letter of `faction` is s *or* first letter of `faction is c *or*...

Like this:

```
if(faction [0] == 's' || faction [0] == 'c' || faction [0] == 'h' || faction [0] == 'd')
```

Of you can use a `switch` statement:

```
string faction;
char type;

cin >> type;

switch (type)
{
case 's':
    faction = "spade";
    break;
case 'c':
    faction = "clib";
    break;
case 'h':
    faction = "heart";
    break;
case 'd':
    faction = "diamond";
    break;
default:
    cout << "Illegal card type\n";
    break;
}
```

The above code also fixes another problem you have, you are using `faction[0]` as both a string and a character. Since you don't specify the type of `faction` I made it a string in my example above.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(functin[0]) {
  case 's': faction = "spade";factionHead_ptr->setLetter("spade");break;
  case 'c': faction = "clubs";factionHead_ptr->setLetter("clubs");break;
  case 'h': faction = "hearts";factionHead_ptr->setLetter("hearts");break;
  case 'd': faction = "diamonds";factionHead_ptr->setLetter("diamonds");break;
  default: cerr<<"wrong suite entered";
}
```